# Bootstrap4 Modal Body not letting div stretch 100% height

Tags: html, css

I created a modal using Bootstrap4 and inside that I have a `div` present in `modal-body`

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" id="myModalDialog">
        <div class="modal-content" id="myModalContent" style="background-color: yellow;">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="myModalTitle">Modal</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="background-color: cadetblue;">
                <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color:aquamarine;">
                    Hello <!-- THIS IS NOT STRETCHING TO 100% HEIGHT -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used CSS to stretch the modal to 100% screen height / width. I used following CSS:

```
#myModalDialog {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            max-width: 100%;
        }

#myModalContent {
            height: auto;
            min-height: 100%;
            border-radius: 0;
        }
```

**What my modal looks is as below.** As you can see the `aquamarine` `div` is not stretching to 100% of height although it is set to `100%` height.

[image]

Comment: You should try putting !important for the min-height property. And make sure you are loading your css after your bootstrap

Comment: I am putting my CSS right in the element, as in code i.e. with the `div`. I tried putting !important, it didn't stretch to 100%

Comment: you could add backgroundColor to #myModalContent to get a better picture of what is going on

Comment: have you tried `<div class="modal-body" style="background-color:aquamarine;">`

Comment: @Uuuuuumm Please see updated code (colors added) with screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this Class `modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable` with  `modal-dialog`

CSS

`#myModalContent{ height:100%; }`

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/gz4L50e3/7/

Comment: It would help to explain to OP, WHY this is your answer.

Comment: min-height added on this class `.modal-dialog-centered` like `min-height: calc(100% - 3.5rem);`

Comment: @LaljiTadhani When I replace my `div` with an `img` with `width: 100%; height: auto;` it is displayed in full size i.e. goes beyond the `modal-body` stretch in height as per the image size leading to scroll. How can I ensure that it stay within `modal-body` and resizes proportionally to fill the area in terms of height ?